# SOAP Request conversion error

Tags: soap, .net-core

Due to a NDA I cannot share any code so hopefully someone can help me here.

I'm trying to do a SOAP call to a backoffice of a client which works until I ask for the result. Now my project is divided into 3 separate project files

- Main App (netcoreapp1.0)
- Models (netcoreapp1.0)
- Services (netcoreapp1.0)

When I execute the async task the following error occurs.

> System.String, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e is not assignable
>   from System.String[], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e

What I can say about the call is that I assign a string to a class that contains one property (string). So I'm not exactly sure what is the problem here.

Hopefully someone had this problem before and can point me to the fix !

Tx

Comment: Is this a similar issue to this one? https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/1274

Comment: could you post the generated SOAP client method without violating the NDA? Perhaps renaming the method name, arguments and anything else that applies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I had 2 dimensions arrays "array[][]", simply I changed the 2 dimensions array "array[][]" to 1 dimension array "array[]" and it works fine. Check this post:
https://forums.asp.net/t/1469891.aspx?Unable+to+generate+a+temporary+class+result+1+error+CS0030+